# Assuming the abc conjecture to prove the Catalan equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to answer the following question:

Assuming the abc-conjecture, show that there are only finitely many sets of integers $x,y>0$ and $p,q>1$ such that $x^p-y^q=1$.

I've attempted to solve this as follows but have gotten stuck.

We can rewrite the above equation as $x^p=y^q+1$, so by the abc conjecture, we have some constant $\kappa_\epsilon>0$ such that

$$\kappa_\epsilon(x^p)^{1-\epsilon} = \prod_{\substack{r \text{ prime} \\ r|xy}}r =  \prod_{\substack{r \text{ prime} \\ r|xy}}r \le xy.$$

I'm not sure what epsilon to choose here to get an appropriate bound. I made some headway proceeding under the assumption that $p>2$. From $x^p=y^q+1$, we can deduce that $y < x^\frac{p}{q} \le x^\frac{p}{2}$, so $xy < x^{1+\frac{p}{2}}$. Noticing that $\frac{1}{2}p+1 \le \frac{9}{10}p$ implies $p \ge \frac{5}{2}$, so we can choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{10}$, to get

$$\kappa_\frac{1}{10}(x^{\frac{9}{10}p}) < x^{1+\frac{p}{2}}$$

from which we can bound x by dividing both sides by $\kappa_\frac{1}{10}x^{1+\frac{p}{2}}$ and raising both sides to the appropriate power. Is what I've done so far correct, and is there a way to amend this approach (or otherwise) to solve this problem for the $p=2$ case? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case $p>2$, this is correct (though you need the *converse* implication, that is, that $0.9p \geq 1+p/2$ when $p\geq 3$).

To deal with the case $p=2$, your method basically still works. Instead of writing $y \leq x^{p/2}$, keep $y \leq x^{p/q}=x^{2/q}$, and use the same trick. It will work when $q>2$.

Only the case $p=q=2$ remains, and I don’t know if abc can directly show that there are finitely many solutions in this case. Fortunately, it’s an easy fact.